# LinqPad 5 : The name 'DbFunctions' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, linqpad, dbfunctions

I am trying to use the following in LinqPad (C# Statement):

```
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(mvOutDt).ToString()
```

It doesn't seems to recognize DbFunctions.  I have added the `System.Data.Entity` reference.  I even tried to fully qualify it using `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions`, but no go.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in LinqPad 5.  Works just fine.  Are you certain you added the correct nuget package version?

Comment: Yeah, my co-worker tried it on his and it works fine. I don't think there is a nuget package for it.  System.Data.Entity is built in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the incorrect version.

The [`DbFunctions` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx) was introduced in Entity Framework 6, which is available via NuGet Package.

If you are using EF 5 or prior, you will not find a `DbFunctions` class in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace, per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity(v=vs.103).aspx).

Comment: What it is looking like.... I am using the basic version which will not allow me to get the Entity Framework 6 package.... my co-worker has the premium version.  So you may be right.

Comment: That would probably do it.  You're pulling from the .NET Framework installed version which would be EF 5 or earlier.